# Cannot resolve symbol `webdriver.chrome.driver` in pom.xml

Tags: java, vaadin, pom.xml

`webdriver.chrome.driver` is not resolved symbol in pom.xml of my project.How to get rid of this error and what is the use of `webdriver.chrome.driver`

```
<configuration>
   <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
   <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
   <systemPropertyVariables>
      <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->                                 
      <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver</webdriver.chrome.driver>
   </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${webdriver.chrome.driver}` references a property in the block. You don't have this property defined. You might wanna add this block with the correct value of the web driver you wanna use

```
<properties>
        <webdriver.chrome.driver>my web driver</webdriver.chrome.driver>
    </properties>
```